# Is there such a thing as a converter from php to html?

Tags: php, html

Don't think that I'm mad, I understand how php works!

That being said. I develop personal website and I usually take advantage of php to avoid repetion during the development phase nothing truly dynamic, only includes for the menus, a couple of foreach and the likes.

When the development phase ends I need to give the website in html files to the client. Is there a tool (crawler?) that can do this for me instead of visiting each page and saving the interpreted html?

Comment: There is a converter that will convert from PHP to HTML, that converter is called PHP :-P

Comment: Quite odd question. I thought geocities-kind html-only hosting is long time dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need something more powerful that recursive wget, httrack works pretty well.  http://www.httrack.com/

Comment: And I happen to benefit from now knowing of this tool too. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use wget to download recursively all the pages linked.

You can read more about this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget#Recursive_download

Comment: +1 for wget. That's how I've done it in the past and would do it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a crawler, I would go for the mighty [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget).

Otherwise you could also use some build tool like [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29).

You need to create a file nameed [Makefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) in the same folder of your php files.
It should contain this:

```
all: 1st_page.html 2nd_page.html 3rd_page.html

1st_page.html: 1st_page.php
    php command

2nd_page.html: 2nd_page.php
    php command

3rd_page.html: 3rd_page.php
    php command
```

Note that the *php command* is not preceded by spaces but by a tabulation.
(See [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) for the php command line syntax.)

After that, whenever you want to update your html files just type

```
make
```

in your terminal to automatically generate them.

It could seem a lot of work for just a simple job, but *make* is a very handy tool that you will find useful to automate other tasks as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Pavuk](http://pavuk.sourceforge.net/) offers much finer control than wget. And will rewrite the URLs in the grabbed pages if required.

Comment: Wow, that tool is incredible! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, [command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) will help?

Comment: @Col I suppose it can execute your PHP scripts and spit out the output.

Comment: yes it can. as well as regular version do. the solution is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, you can use [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) to crawl a web-site.